# Calling remote method of shared objects in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I am not to add method to a remote shared object in AS3. In AS2 
this code used to work

```
SharedObjectName.MethodName = function(){}
```

But this code is not working for AS3. I searched in Google and other AS3 forums but didn't get any help.

can anyone provide a pointer to me please.

Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally solved it somehow,

this is what i did

class abc
{
public function MessageFromServer()
{

}

SharedObject.client= this;
}
this allows the FMS server to control this client's public methods, Which I Wanted.

IN FMS I can call this as -

SharedObject.call("MessageFromServer")

Answer (score 2):

SharedObject is not a dynamic class, which means you can't add properties to it à la JavaScript (apparently, objects in AS2 behave the same way, but I never used AS2, so I can't tell). Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to subclass SharedObject or create a wrapper class.